Help with Schengen visa application
My girlfriend and I are planning a summer trip to Spain to attend a sports event, and we need advice on applying for a Spanish tourist visa. We want to ensure we submit the right documents to support a good premise, especially given some potential red flags in our profiles (passport, age, online job...). We also want to assess the likelihood of our application being accepted, as we prefer not to apply if our chances are slim.
Here's some background information:
I am a 26-year-old male with a Tunisian passport. For the past three years, my 21-year-old girlfriend (also Tunisian) and I have been traveling extensively in Asia as digital nomads. We've lived legally in Thailand and Indonesia and visited countries such as Singapore, Malaysia, UAE, and India for tourism. Recently, we've established a two-year residency in Indonesia to invest and live here long-term. So we plan to apply for a Spanish tourist visa from Indonesia.
I have been an entrepreneur since 2019, running an e-commerce startup founded in the USA, which I managed remotely from my home country and then from Thailand and Indonesia as I relocated to Southeast Asia. I have 15+ employees and a consistent multiple six-figure yearly personal income. I maintain substantial balances in both my business and personal accounts, although these are with online banks like Wise and Mercury. My girlfriend works for me as the head of marketing, also earning a respectable income.
Our ties to Indonesia include an investment company sponsoring our residency here, a long-term rental agreement for a $2500/month villa, and my brother, who lives with us but will not be traveling to Spain. Additionally, I have a widowed mother in Tunisia whom I support financially which might be accounted as ties to Tunisia.
Our main reason for visiting Spain is to attend a Padel Tennis training Camp in Malaga and watch the world Padel tournament.
Given our income situation, I think it's clear that we will not seek employment in Spain or any part of Europe, especially since our income is well above the average in Europe. However, we recognize that our profiles may raise concerns with the consular office. We're seeking advice on how to provide additional evidence to offset any red flags without overwhelming the visa officer.
Additionally, can anyone recommend a community-recommended service to review the coherence of our documents and application before submission? Are there any visa agents you would recommend? We are eager to attend this event and are ready to invest significantly to ensure our visa application is successful.
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

I'm not sure the "ties to Tunisia" bit, when you are actually living on the other side of the planet, is a good idea. What is the actual source of the income? Salary? Dividends? Where from (i.e. which company, based where)? Can you provide evidence of that, matching credits onto your bank account? How long have you lived in Indonesia? While you present a very positive picture, it's probably important for you to be able to document it properly. Simple, obvious applications are always better, like a single bank account receiving a regular, monthly income supported by matching salary slips.

Don’t over-think it is my advice. Make a list of the eligibility criteria and categorise them into ‘meet/ have evidence’, ‘partially meet/have evidence’, ‘do not meet’ etc., then decide how to address the weak areas. Reading the relevant questions here and comparing your situation to the ones described will give you a good idea of the pitfalls and how to avoid them, and of your chances of success.

If you are applying for short term visa then most importantly you should provide information about your intention to return , do you have the invitation letter or proof of registration of the event taking place. Spain rejected almost 19 % of visa applications and Tunisians stood 6th highest in 2022 according to this source ! https://www.portugalresidencyadvisors.com/schengen-countries-with-high-visa-rejection/ . You could try your luck honestly it’s like a lottery no amount of paperwork and documents can guarantee you entry but you must definitely get a reliable immigration lawyer !

@jcaron's source of income is both salary and dividends, which are exclusively coming from my company, which is based in Delaware, US. My bank statements show frequent incoming transactions from my business that are not always the same amount and are not monthly, as I tend to withdraw different amounts weekly based on my needs. My April statement for example shows many credits totaling $26,757.95 and $26,545.38 in withdraws (I tend to spend what I withdraw from the business). And I do have an account balance of around $19,000 in another bank account. I lived in Indonesia for 14 months.

@SaranshSharma, yes, I have the booking confirmation, and I can request an official invitation letter from the organizer.

@br88 Personal and company tax filings will be important, along with bank statements.

Do you have documentation to support the credits from your company to your personal account? They usually don't like large unexplained credits (search for "funds parking"). Also read https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105 (applies to the UK, but the logic is the same for Schengen). A good immigration lawyer (based in Spain, not Indonesia) may be a good idea to make sure your application's (huge) strengths are not marred by an application that is incorrectly supported.

The odds look good not on the basis of money but the overall application, they are there to point out mistakes in your application and one mistake could result in visa refusal. You should first look at the overall requirements instead of fixing on money and transactions , your focus should be on returning back and demonstrating that you need to return to Indonesia because you have a rental agreement, you have some liabilities or responsibilities. How many days are you planning to go ? If this is your first time then you should carefully put your visa application, honestly it’s easy

I wasn't sure that immigration lawyers could help with Tourist visas. But after many of you recommended hiring a lawyer, I decided to go that route. Do you know how to find a good one in Spain? I contacted a few Spanish immigration law firms with a simple Google search, but I don't know how would I assess their reliability with Schengen Visas. Are there any specifics to look for in such a lawyer? One lawyer already replied and is pushing the nonlucrative visa to me, but it takes time and won't allow me to attend the event.

@SaranshSharma Indeed, I realize it's not about money. That's why I'm posting here. I need to find ways to prove with strong evidence that I will return to Indonesia, but the first that comes to mind appears weak/hard to prove. I plan to go there for two weeks.  The first one for the event in Malaga, then I'll choose another touristic destination in Spain to explore.

If I think about it honestly there are a few reasons why I will be returning to Bali. 1- I LOVE my lifestyle in Bali (not sure how I can prove that) 2- I also own a company in Bali and plan to invest in real estate here, but I still don't have any income from Indonesia. 3- My brother and friends are in Bali with me. 4- I have an apartment with so much stuff that I can't just abandon. But the question is how to communicate this to the officer lol

@SaranshSharma Personal contact via TSE is not allowed.

Does this answer your question? Schengen Visa Application: what are some helpful tips for preparing?

People post answers, not comments.
